# ES6: Find an object in an array by one of its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in ES6...

I have this array of objects..

```
const originalData=[
{"investor": "Sue", "value": 5, "investment": "stocks"},
{"investor": "Rob", "value": 15, "investment": "options"},
{"investor": "Sue", "value": 25, "investment": "savings"},
{"investor": "Rob", "value": 15, "investment": "savings"},
{"investor": "Sue", "value": 2, "investment": "stocks"},
{"investor": "Liz", "value": 85, "investment": "options"},
{"investor": "Liz", "value": 16, "investment": "options"}
];
```

..and this new array of objects where I want to add each person's total value of their investment types (stocks, options, savings)..

```
const newData = [
{"investor":"Sue", "stocks": 0, "options": 0, "savings": 0},
{"investor":"Rob", "stocks": 0, "options": 0, "savings": 0},
{"investor":"Liz", "stocks": 0, "options": 0, "savings": 0}
];
```

I loop through originalData and save each property of the "current object" in a let..

```
for (let obj of originalData) {
   let currinvestor = obj.investor;
   let currinvestment = obj.investment;
   let currvalue = obj.value;

   ..but here I want to find the obect in newData that has the property = currinvestor (for the "investor" key)
   ...then add that investment type's (currinvestment) value (currvalue) 
}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
newData.find(x => x.investor === investor)
```

And the whole code:

```js
const originalData = [
  { "investor": "Sue",   "value":  5,   "investment": "stocks"  },
  { "investor": "Rob",   "value": 15,   "investment": "options" },
  { "investor": "Sue",   "value": 25,   "investment": "savings" },
  { "investor": "Rob",   "value": 15,   "investment": "savings" },
  { "investor": "Sue",   "value":  2,   "investment": "stocks"  },
  { "investor": "Liz",   "value": 85,   "investment": "options" },
  { "investor": "Liz",   "value": 16,   "investment": "options" },
];

const newData = [
  { "investor": "Sue",   "stocks": 0,   "options": 0,   "savings": 0 },
  { "investor": "Rob",   "stocks": 0,   "options": 0,   "savings": 0 },
  { "investor": "Liz",   "stocks": 0,   "options": 0,   "savings": 0 },
];

for (let {investor, value, investment} of originalData) {
  newData.find(x => x.investor === investor)[investment] += value;
}

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use some derivative of this:

```
    var arrayFindObjectByProp = (arr, prop, val) => {
        return arr.find( obj => obj[prop] == val );
    };
```