# What is the simplest way to search in JSON by attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
"names": [
    {
        "id": 17,
        "user_id": 9,
        "code": "de",
        "name": "Ich bin Hans",
        "created_at": "2017-07-31 12:43:19",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-31 12:43:19"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "user_id": 9,
        "code": "en",
        "name": "My name is Hans",
        "created_at": "2017-07-31 12:43:19",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-31 12:43:19"
    }
]
```

Is there any method to get JSON object with `code='en'`  from the above JSON array in jQuery?

I could do it with `for`loop but I thought maybe there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6: Find an object in an array by one of its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235353/es6-find-an-object-in-an-array-by-one-of-its-properties)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function in vanilla JS to *filter* out the object - see demo below:

```js
var obj={names:[{id:17,user_id:9,code:"de",name:"Ich bin Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"},{id:18,user_id:9,code:"en",name:"My name is Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"}]};

var result = obj.names.filter(function(e){return e.code == 'en'})
console.log(result);
```

ES6 version is even simpler:

```js
var obj={names:[{id:17,user_id:9,code:"de",name:"Ich bin Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"},{id:18,user_id:9,code:"en",name:"My name is Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"}]};

var result = obj.names.filter(e => e.code == 'en');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [Jquery grep function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/). Actually you are not searching object, you are searching though an array of objects (*names*).

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.

```js
 var input = {names:[{id:17,user_id:9,code:"de",name:"Ich bin Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"},{id:18,user_id:9,code:"en",name:"My name is Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"}]};
 
var result = $.grep(input.names, function(obj) {
    return obj.code === "en";
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another is [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function

```js
var input = {names:[{id:17,user_id:9,code:"de",name:"Ich bin Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"},{id:18,user_id:9,code:"en",name:"My name is Hans",created_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19",updated_at:"2017-07-31 12:43:19"}]};
 
var result = input.names.find(item => {
   return item.code == 'en'
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `$.grep` corresponds to ES5 `filter`, not ES6 `find`

Comment: @Bergi `grep` and `find` are no where related ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it with a for loop, try the ES5 array function, filter

```
names = names.filer(function(item) {
  return item.code === 'en'
})
```