# Object.keys() and find

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Struggling to understand why I get an error when I try to use [ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235353/es6-find-an-object-in-an-array-by-one-of-its-properties) `.find` on this data below.  I'm trying to get the record with id number 3.

```
{
 {id:10,title:'Dairy & Eggs'}
 {id:7,title:'Laundry & Househo,}
 {id:9,title:'Bakery'}
 {id:8,title:'Fresh Food'}
 {id:4,title:'Frozen Food'}
 {id:6,title:'Health & Beauty'}
 {id:3,title:'Food Cupboard'}
 {id:5,title:'Drinks'}
 {id:2,title:'Chilled Food'}
}
```

I tried

```
 const category = categories.find(function (category) { return category.id === 3; } 

 console.log(category)
```

and

```
const category = categories.filter(category => category.id === 3) 
console.log(category)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your data using JSON syntax. Is that an array or an object?

Comment: I'm not sure what that first snippet is, it seems like invalid syntax. Maybe it's some new feature I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: What does the title have to do with your question - you're not using `Object.keys` anywhere?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin No, it is plainly invalid syntax indeed, not a new feature

Comment: **What error** are you getting when trying your code?

Comment: I'm learning reactjs and redux. I'm trying to loop through the state and find one record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** works over array not on object.

Either you need to change your Data to Array of Objects as

```
[
 {id:10,title:'Dairy & Eggs'},
 {id:7,title:'Laundry & Househo'},
 {id:9,title:'Bakery'},
 {id:8,title:'Fresh Food'},
 {id:4,title:'Frozen Food'},
 {id:6,title:'Health & Beauty'},
 {id:3,title:'Food Cupboard'},
 {id:5,title:'Drinks'},
 {id:2,title:'Chilled Food'}
]
```

**DEMO**

```js
 var categories = [
  {
    "id": 10,
    "title": "Dairy & Eggs"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Laundry & Househo"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "title": "Bakery"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Fresh Food"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Frozen Food"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "title": "Health & Beauty"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Food Cupboard"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Drinks"
  }
];
const category = categories.filter(category => category.id === 3) ; 
console.log(category)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, works.   ` let fromState = Object.keys(categories).map(key => categories[key])
    const category = fromState.find(function (category) { return category.id === 3; });`