# JS Reduce and group JSON by deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, reducers

I'm pulling via REST a JSON with an array of objects with some fields and some nested objects.

What I'm trying to create is a grouped summary object from the array of nested JSON objects with the following structure:

```
 var data = [
        {
            "Id": 79,
            "Date": "2019-02-17T00:00:00-07:00",
            "StartTime": 1535385600,
            "EndTime": 1535416200,
            "Slots": [
                {
                    "blnEmptySlot": false,
                    "strType": "B",
                    "intStart": 3600,
                    "intEnd": 5400,
                    "intUnixStart": 1535389200,
                    "intUnixEnd": 1535391000,
                }
            ],
            "OperationalUnit": 3,
            "Created": "2019-01-31T11:23:29+02:00",
            "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00",
            "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00",
            "_MetaData": {
                "AttendeeInfo": {
                    "Id": 111,
                    "AttendeeDisplayName": "att_name1",
                    "AttendeeProfile": 406,
                    "Attendee": 406,
                    "Photo": "avatar_path"
                  },
                "OperationalUnitInfo": {
                    "Id": 3,
                    "OperationalUnitName": "op_unit_name",
                    "Company": 1,
                    "CompanyName": "comp_name",
                    "LabelWithCompany": "comp_label"
                },
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": 80,
            "Date": "2019-02-17T00:00:00-07:00",
            "StartTime": 1535385600,
            "EndTime": 1535416200,
            "Slots": [
                {
                    "blnEmptySlot": false,
                    "strType": "B",
                    "intStart": 3600,
                    "intEnd": 5400,
                    "intUnixStart": 1535389200,
                    "intUnixEnd": 1535391000,
                }
            ],
            "OperationalUnit": 3,
            "Created": "2019-01-31T11:23:29+02:00",
            "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00",
            "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00",
            "_MetaData": {
                "AttendeeInfo": {
                    "Id": 112,
                    "AttendeeDisplayName": "att_name2",
                    "AttendeeProfile": 407,
                    "Attendee": 407,
                    "Photo": "avatar_path"
                  },
                "OperationalUnitInfo": {
                    "Id": 3,
                    "OperationalUnitName": "op_unit_name",
                    "Company": 1,
                    "CompanyName": "comp_name",
                    "LabelWithCompany": "comp_label"
                },
            }
        }
    ];
```

The overall purpose is to create a list of event objects with start and end DateTime, a LabelWithCompany String (deep nested object)  and a list of all Attendees grouped by OperationalUnitName and Start and End times.

Example :

```
[
    {
        "2019-02-17T00:00:00-08:00": {//Date
            "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00": {//StartTimeLocalized
                "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00": {//EndTimeLocalized
                    "[NYC] Network - Solutions": {//LabelWithCompany
                        "attendees": [
                            "att_name1",//AttendeeDisplayName
                            "att_name2"  //AttendeeDisplayName    
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I assume that map and reduce are the necessary functions, but I had trouble with doing  multiple nested reduces.
Any other suggestion how to aggregate these objects to into an aggregated format that will contain all the attendees for each session.

Comment: where do you get `'att1'` and so on, from? why do you have an array as result set?

Comment: You don't need multiple `reduce`, one is enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235590/4928642

Comment: please add a result which reflects the given data.

Comment: @NinaScholz I've edited the input and the output examples.
I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: How are you coming up with the keys in your output? The string `"2019-02-18T00:00:00-08:00"` appears nowhere in your input.

Comment: My apologies, edited once again, this time with comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take some helper function for getting the value of a nested object and for setting a path and returning the last nested object by taking an array of keys.

Then you need to take the keys for the nested result set an another for getting the value for pushing to the result.

```js
const
    getValue = (object, path) => [].concat(path).reduce((o, k) => o[k], object),
    setPath = (object, path) => [].concat(path).reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object);

var data = [{ Id: 79, Date: "2018-08-27T00:00:00-07:00", StartTime: 1535385600, EndTime: 1535416200, Slots: [{ blnEmptySlot: false, strType: "B", intStart: 3600, intEnd: 5400, intUnixStart: 1535389200, intUnixEnd: 1535391000 }], OperationalUnit: 3, Created: "2019-01-31T11:23:29+02:00", StartTimeLocalized: "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00", EndTimeLocalized: "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00", _MetaData: { AttendeeInfo: { Id: 111, AttendeeDisplayName: "att_name1", AttendeeProfile: 406, Attendee: 406, Photo: "avatar_path" }, OperationalUnitInfo: { Id: 3, OperationalUnitName: "op_unit_name", Company: 1, CompanyName: "comp_name", LabelWithCompany: "comp_label" } } }, { Id: 80, Date: "2018-08-27T00:00:00-07:00", StartTime: 1535385600, EndTime: 1535416200, Slots: [{ blnEmptySlot: false, strType: "B", intStart: 3600, intEnd: 5400, intUnixStart: 1535389200, intUnixEnd: 1535391000 }], OperationalUnit: 3, Created: "2019-01-31T11:23:29+02:00", StartTimeLocalized: "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00", EndTimeLocalized: "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00", _MetaData: { AttendeeInfo: { Id: 112, AttendeeDisplayName: "att_name2", AttendeeProfile: 407, Attendee: 407, Photo: "avatar_path" }, OperationalUnitInfo: { Id: 3, OperationalUnitName: "op_unit_name", Company: 1, CompanyName: "comp_name", LabelWithCompany: "comp_label" } } }],
    keys = ["Date", "StartTimeLocalized", "EndTimeLocalized", ["_MetaData", "OperationalUnitInfo", "LabelWithCompany"]],
    value = ["_MetaData", "AttendeeInfo", "AttendeeDisplayName"],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = setPath(r, keys.map(getValue.bind(null, o)));

        temp.attendees = temp.attendees || [];
        temp.attendees.push(getValue(o, value));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to reformat it to a way it will be easier create google calendar events from the parsed data ?

Comment: sorry, i don't know the calendar api.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it is possible to reformat the json output to an array of "shifts" which could be easier to iterate through the layers of the nested object.
E.g : 
shifts = [
    {
        Date : "2019-02-17T00:00:00-08:00", 
        StartTimeLocalized : "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00",
        EndTimeLocalized   : "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00",
        LabelWithCompany   : "[NYC] Network - Solutions",
        attendees : [ "att_name1","att_name2" ]
    }, ANOTHER SHIFT OBJECT, ...]

Comment: it looks like a different question. but it is possible.

Comment: I've posted it as another question, thank you Nina !
Your help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to ease the creation of the hierarchy (`drill`), and then iterate over the records, like this:

```js
const data = [{"Id": 79,"Date": "2019-02-17T00:00:00-07:00","StartTime": 1535385600,"EndTime": 1535416200,"Slots": [{"blnEmptySlot": false,"strType": "B","intStart": 3600,"intEnd": 5400,"intUnixStart": 1535389200,"intUnixEnd": 1535391000,}],"OperationalUnit": 3,"Created": "2019-01-31T11:23:29+02:00","StartTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00","EndTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00","_MetaData": {"AttendeeInfo": {"Id": 111,"AttendeeDisplayName": "att_name1","AttendeeProfile": 406,"Attendee": 406,"Photo": "avatar_path"},"OperationalUnitInfo": {"Id": 3,"OperationalUnitName": "op_unit_name","Company": 1,"CompanyName": "comp_name","LabelWithCompany": "comp_label"},}},{"Id": 80,"Date": "2019-02-17T00:00:00-07:00","StartTime": 1535385600,"EndTime": 1535416200,"Slots": [{"blnEmptySlot": false,"strType": "B","intStart": 3600,"intEnd": 5400,"intUnixStart": 1535389200,"intUnixEnd": 1535391000,}],"OperationalUnit": 3,"Created": "2019-01-31T11:23:29+02:00","StartTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T10:00:00+02:00","EndTimeLocalized": "2019-02-17T19:00:00+02:00","_MetaData": {"AttendeeInfo": {"Id": 112,"AttendeeDisplayName": "att_name2","AttendeeProfile": 407,"Attendee": 407,"Photo": "avatar_path"},"OperationalUnitInfo": {"Id": 3,"OperationalUnitName": "op_unit_name","Company": 1,"CompanyName": "comp_name","LabelWithCompany": "comp_label"},}}];

const drill = (o, key, ...keys) => key ? drill(o[key] = o[key] || {}, ...keys) : o; 

const result = {};    
for (const e of data) {
    const key = drill(result, e.Date, 
                              e.StartTimeLocalized, 
                              e.EndTimeLocalized, 
                              e._MetaData.OperationalUnitInfo.LabelWithCompany);
    key.attendees = (key.attendees || []).concat(
                              e._MetaData.AttendeeInfo.AttendeeDisplayName);
}

console.log(result);
```

NB: there seems no use to wrap the output in an array, but you can of course do that.